# Batch script to open a text file in Notepad++

Tags: batch-file, notepad++, command-line-arguments

I basically have a file, for example, `something.txt`, and I want to be able to automatically open up that file using Notepad++.

I had atempted using the `start` command in a batch file, but i didnt understand much, so I just came here to ask you.

Comment: `<full path to>\notepad++ "something.txt"`

Comment: Ok :D Is that for the start command? I guess so

Comment: `start` is not needed. Just execute the program `Notepad++` with the filename as parameter.

Comment: Ok :D Done it :D It worked, thanks very much

Comment: It may be safer to use `@Start "" "%ProgramFiles%\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "F:\ull\Path to\something.txt"` or `@Start "" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "F:\ull\Path to\something.txt"`, depending upon the install location of the program. I'll be surprised however if the installation didn't add the respective registry entry under `[HKLM|HKCU]\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\notepad++.exe`, to save you having to provide its full path. If `something.txt` is in the current directory, and your `%PATHEXT%` contains `.EXE`, just use `@Start notepad++ something.txt`.

Comment: Read [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this
(don't forget the double quotes)

```
"C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" something.txt
```

Comment: Hey, I put this line you sent me here onto a start command and it still started normally on the default notepad.

Comment: Ok I looked at the other comments, people said that I don't need start. I removed it. It worked. Thanks everyone.

Comment: If you don't use `Start`, and you're trying it from a batch script, the script will wait for it to be closed before it continues or closes. If there are no more commands to run after opening your file in Notepad++, and you use `Start` the `cmd.exe` window will close instead of staying open in the background. If there are more commands to run, and they're not dependent upon having read the file content and closed `Notepad++`, `Start` will mean that those commands will continue to run without waiting for you to close `Notepad++`. Open a Command Prompt window and enter `start /?` for its info.

Comment: @MantvydasViršilas please accept the answer if you are happy with it ;-)

Comment: @Mantvydas: `start` takes the first quoted string as a window title, so when you added `start` you opened an (unneeded) `cmd` instance with the title `C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe`, which in turn starts `something.txt` with its default editor (which happens to be the Windows Notepad). If you need to use `start` for some reason, the syntax would be `start "title" "program" "parameter"`